# Can't make a bullet list in reStructuredtext (Sphinx/readthedocs) in the format that I want?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to make a simple nested bullet list within an enumerated list. I have a list in numerical order, but when I try to add a bullet list within this list, the bullets are numbers. Take a look:

I want this:

```
1. Sample 1
     * Sub bullet 1
     * Sub bullet 2
2. Sample 2
     * Sub bullet 1
```

In the reStructuredtext I did this:

```
#. Sample 1
     * ``sub bullet 1``
     * ``sub bullet 2``
#. Sample 2
     * ``sub bullet 1``
```

But the output of this on readthedocs turns into:

```
1. Sample 1
    1. Sub bullet 1
    2. Sub bullet 2
2. Sample 2
    1. Sub bullet 1
```

What I'm doing wrong? I tried playing with the indentations, preceding and proceeding white space lines, etc., but to no avail.

Comment: it works for me; what is your set-up?

Comment: I get jake9115's output when using sphinx_rtd_theme locally. Works fine with the default theme, but not the readthedocs theme as mentioned in their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the sphinx_rtd_theme which is currently used as the default theme on readthedocs, so you should probably fill an issue at it's github page. In the meantime you can use this workaround:

```
1. Sample 1

  * ``sub bullet 1``
  * ``sub bullet 2``

2. Sample 2

  * ``sub bullet 1``
```

The bad thing here is that you have to number your enumerated list by hand, also the indentation of the bullet list is not really correct, but it works and builds documentation without errors with the sphinx_rtd_theme.

Or you can switch to another theme (e.g. default) where this type of markup is parsed correctly.

Comment: Great, I knew I couldn't be misinterpreting this markup that badly! Glad to use the fix.

Comment: Has this been fixed upstream yet?

Comment: This is fixed as of sphinx_rtd_theme 0.5.2.